# ¿Como hacer que se muestren los archivos de texto?

Tags: java

En mi código no soy capaz de que los archivos txt aparezcan en pantalla, no se que me falta para que esto funcione. Este es mi código hasta ahora. Solo incluyo la parte esencial,hay otras clases pero no creo que sean el problema que tengo

```
public static ArrayList<Caballeros> seleccionarFichero() {
    Scanner entrada = null;
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.showOpenDialog(fc);
    try {
        ArrayList<Caballeros> Personajes = new ArrayList<Caballeros>(); 
        File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
        // File f = new File("Datos_personajes\\Personajes.txt");
        entrada = new Scanner(f);
        while (entrada.hasNext()) {
            String mensaje = entrada.nextLine();
            String[] splitter = mensaje.split(";");
            Personajes.add(new Caballeros(splitter[0], splitter[1], 0, 0, 0, null, splitter[2], mensaje, mensaje, Integer.parseInt(splitter[3]), false));
        }
        return Personajes;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("No se ha seleccionado ningún fichero");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (entrada != null) {
            entrada.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [**ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). El código que compartes es insuficiente. ¿En qué tipo de componente mostrarás el contenido del archivo? Sólo has puesto el código de carga, pero no cómo ese `ArrayList<Caballeros>` es volcado a un componente gráfico que muestre su contenido.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no eres capaz de mostrar los archivos en pantalla? ¿Tienes algún error? Acabo de ejecutar tu código y funciona correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una clase que uso para leer archivos en una app android.
Primero compruebo que exista el archivo con un método que llamé `"ArchivoExiste"` y si el `if` da true lo leo.
Uso `ImputStreamReader` y `BufferReader`. Con `readLine` leo la primer línea antes del `while` para ver que no este vacía y si no lo está entonces sí en el `while` leerá todas hasta encontrar la primera vacía y ahí termina el lazo.
Después cierro el archivo y en este caso armo para ver lo leído en una lista.
No se si te pueda ayudar con esto. Me comentas cualquier cosa.

```
   public void leoFichero(String nombfich) {
    /* **** Si es que existe muestro listado **** */

    String nombrefichero = nombfich; // nombre del archivo
    String[] archivos = fileList(); // ruta al archivo
    listamaqcompleta = "";
    if (ArchivoExiste(archivos, nombrefichero)) {
        try {
            InputStreamReader archivo = null;
            try {
                archivo = new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(nombrefichero));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(archivo);
            //ArrayList<String> lista_maquinas = new ArrayList<>();
            lista_maquinas.clear();
            String line = br.readLine();

            // String listamaqcompleta = "";
            cant_item = 0;
            while (line != null) {

                listamaqcompleta = listamaqcompleta + line + "\n";
                lista_maquinas.add(line);
                line = br.readLine();
                cant_item++;
            }
            br.close();
            archivo.close();
            ArrayAdapter adapter_listview = new ArrayAdapter< >(this, R.layout.item_listview_1, lista_maquinas);
            lv_lista.setAdapter(adapter_listview);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // poner aviso de error
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_campos) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Dicho sea, ¿en qué soluciona tu respuesta a la duda planteada?